# How do you "shear" a snow golem's face?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend has an IPad that he plays Minecraft on. He took shears and tapped a snow golem's face. Then suddenly, the pumpkin head disappeared and was replaced by smiley face. On PC though, I left and right clicked it's face with a shear but nothing happened. Is it possible to do this on PC?

P.S. Another way to see the smiley face is to go inside the golem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Minecraft PC 1.9 snapshot 15w49a Shearing snow golems' pumpkin is no longer exclusive to minecraft PE. With this snapshot players can now shear snow golem's pumpkin by right clicking on them with shears.

Answer (score 9):

It can only be done in the pocket edition. If you look at the [Minecraft Wiki for snow golems](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snow_Golem), you'll see under the change log for the Pocket Edition:

> Snow golems' pumpkin can now be removed with shears. **This is version exclusive.**

Comment: One day it will come to PC, as always :) In case somebody needs that.

Answer (score -1):

Just get a shear (two iron ingots in a crafting table) and face the golem. At the bottom of your android or iOS device it says shear. If you click it the golems face turns derpy. That's all I know for know. But on the other hand it is only for MCPE and no release of word has come out of it in The Pc Version. It's just a little Easter egg in MCPE for the curious people. There are many more Easter eggs to find in mcpe so keep your eyes out.

Comment: This answer adds nothing (relevant) that hasn't been mentioned already. Duplicate answers are useless and therefore frowned upon here on Arqade.

Answer (score -1):

Yup, if you want to shear a snow golem's face, you need to use a shear. It cannot be done in PC. Once the snow golem has been sheared, the face turns derpy with NO pumpkin. :)